# AAD Object ID of a rooms on running https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have the following code to get rooms from graph:

```
            var roomUrl = graphClient.Places.AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("microsoft.graph.room");
            var response= await new GraphServicePlacesCollectionRequest(roomUrl, graphClient, null).GetAsync();
            if (response.CurrentPage.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var room in response.CurrentPage)
                {  
                    Console.WriteLine(room.Id);
                }
            }
```

room.Id represents RoomId which is different from AAD object Id of the room.

Is there a way to get object Id of the room instead of room Id in the response?

Comment: We can see the [api document about the response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/place-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response), it will return a `place` object which doesn't contain the object ID propertity.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to call another endpoint.

Take an `emailAddress` of the room and call Users endpoint. Users endpoint doesn't return only users but also rooms.

```
var roomMail = room.EmailAddress;
var roomUser = await graphClient.Users[roomMail].Request().GetAsync();
// read AAD object id
var aadObjectId = roomUser.Id;
```

Comment: Thank you! Let’s say I have a list of 1000 rooms. Should I use a for loop to get object I’d of all rooms? Or is there any alternate way?

Comment: @user989988 1000 rooms is a lot. Graph API doesn't provide any alternate way to get aad object id of all rooms by one call. Unfortunately you need get aad object id for each room one by one in for loop.

Comment: can I use batch request to get object ids of all the rooms? Could you please give an example?

Comment: Using batch request is another option. You can either read the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/batch-requests?tabs=csharp or create a new question please.

Comment: Please see the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73847666/batch-request-to-collect-the-object-ids-c Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73847666/batch-request-to-collect-the-object-ids-c Could you please answer?