# Batch request to collect the object ids [C#]

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

How do I create a batch request to collect the object ids of a list of users?

```
var roomMail = room.EmailAddress;
var roomUser = await graphClient.Users[roomMail].Request().GetAsync();
var aadObjectId = roomUser.Id;
```

Comment: ms graph api for [list users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) doesn't provide a batch option. so you may need to write a foreach to realize your requirement.

Comment: Please let me where in the doc it is mentioned

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDkql.png

Comment: If it is a batch request, how will it be specified?

Comment: Also, what apis are supported by batch requests?

Comment: I don't know it.

Comment: Hello. Do you want to collect object ids for different users queries?

Comment: Object ids of different rooms that I get from calling (get places/microsoft.graph.room)